# How to check routes with unit testing on Laravel5

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5

I tried using unit testing, but it doesn't work. Somehow, Received status code is 404. Then, terminal stated the reason is an exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException'.

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('toppage')->with('contents', "");
});
```

ExampleTest.php

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Where lane');
    }
}
```

nignx.conf (excerpt a part from the file)

```
location / {
        index            index.html index.php;
    }

    location ~* /MAMP(.*)$ {
        root             /Applications/MAMP/bin;
        index            index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files        $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass     unix:/Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi/nginxFastCGI.sock;
            fastcgi_param    SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include          fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see if you can access the route. It's best to verify a text that will be on that link.

Try this:

```
class WelcomeTest extends TestCase {

    /**
     * Test if the public index page returns the correct view
     * GET /
     */

    public function testWelcomePage()
    {
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/');

        // check if we're getting the default welcome page. 
        //you can replace this with something on your default route's <title> Html tag

        $this->assertRegexp('/<title>Welcome<\/title>/', $response->getContent());

    }

}
```

If this fails, then try getting the site in your browser first. Clear your routes, cache and double check if the text "Where lane" acually exists on the page.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Based on your idea, I created a test and checked it worked!!  Then, I checked the code, $this->visit ('/'), didn't work as I expected. The result was failed because of NotFoundHttpException. Although I don't understand the detail reason, I will create test cases with your thought.

Comment: Awesome, You should change your route to something like this 

" Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index'); "
and then run 

" php artisan route:cache "

verify the route is going to the right place 
" php artisan route:list "

I think this should make $this->visit ('/')  work too. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you for your additional advice. At least I haven't typed those commands on the terminal. So, I will post the answer if solved.

Comment: After verifying the route, I tried "$this->visit('/')", but it return failure and 404 as return code. However the code "$this->get('/')"  worked. Just in case, I reported it to you.